# Creating an object from database data and appending it to a QList

Tags: c++, qt

Why can't I call append on this QList?

```
QList<Artist> * DataManagement::create_and_get_artists(){

    QList<Artist> *artists = new QList<Artist>;

    for(int i; i < m_allSongs->rowCount(); i++){
        Artist *artist = new Artist();
        artist->setName(m_allSongs->record(i).value("artistName").toString());
        artists->append(artist);

    }

    return artists;
}
```

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYsLB.png)

Error message: "no matching member function for call to 'append'".

Comment: Please don't post images of code and error messages. They are text and should be posted as text.

Comment: Append takes a parameter. Your error picture attempted to call it without a parameter. With that said the code has changed between the picture of the error which showed `artists->append();` and the text code presented in the question which shows `artists->append(artist);`

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html#append) (*always* check the documentation first!).

There are two overloads of `append()`:

`void QList::append(const T &value)`

and

`void QList::append(const QList<T> &value)`

So you can append a value or a list of values.

In your code on the screenshot, you call `artists->append();`.
That is, you are not providing any argument. No member function `append()` with zero arguments exist.

**Managing Object Lifetimes**

Remember that you are responsible for managing memory in C++!
You have a `QList<Artist>`, i.e., a list of actual objects. Yet you create an Artist using `new`. Now you have a **pointer** to a heap allocated object.

Calling `append(obj)` will actually **copy** the object, i.e., call the copy constructor! You are then responsible to free the temporary object you created!

Alternatively, you could use a `QList<Artist*>`, i.e., a list of pointers. But I think this is the worst option.

You could also construct a temporary object on the stack and then copy it:

```
Artist artist{};
artist.setName("bla");
artists->append(artist);
```

But it would be much better - if you use Qt6 - to just construct the object directly into the list, using [emplaceBack()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlist.html#emplaceBack).
(You need the matching constructor, of course).

Comment: Yeah thanks, my bad! I was playing around with it and then forgot to parse the argument with the append function. artists->append(artist); still got the error

Comment: First off, you should update your question removing the screenshot and adding the new error message (or is it the same? I doubt it).

Secondly, like I wrote in my answer: You want an `Artist` but you are passing a **pointer** to an Artist (i.e., `Artist*`) to append.

Comment: Thanks for answering so fast! The error message is the same. But i don't understand how i create a new artist object in the for loop, if  i type Artist artist = new Artist(); i got the error message "no viable conversion from Artist* to Artist"

Comment: I would expect ***no viable conversion from Artist* to Artist"*** for `Artist artist = new Artist();` because `new Artist()` is a `Artist*` but `Artist artist` is an `Artist`. I question why you want all these pointers. I think you want to get rid of the pointers and the use of `new` in all cases for this function.

Comment: @DreckigerDan sorry, but it seems like you are missing some C++ fundamentals! Please read up on pointers (https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/introduction-to-pointers/) and dynamic memory allocation with "new" (https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/dynamic-memory-allocation-with-new-and-delete/).

Besides, I have already given you 3 possible solutions in my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! helped me a lot.

Comment: OK. You can accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* call append on a QList type, but only with an appropriate parameter.

In the code, `artist` is a *pointer* to the `Artist` type, while the QList is a list of `Artist` types.

In the screenshot, no parameter is given at all.